# Multipass mount folder on zfs file system - Source path does not exist

Tags: zfsonlinux, multipass

I am trying to add storage to an existing Multipass VM.  I created a new ZFS filesystem, mounted locally at `/zfs/morespace`.  Then tried to mount it with

```
multipass mount /zfs/morespace existingvm:/mnt/morespace
```

I received the error:

> Source path "/zfs/morespace" does not exist

When I `ls /zfs` "morespace" is listed.
I also created a folder `/zfs/morespace/storagedir` and tried to mount that with the same result.

Can anyone help me understand why Multipass cannot find the zfs file system or directories inside of it, while ubuntu has no issue?  Most of my storage is on a large zpool with multiple zfs file systems, and I would like to be able to utilize this for extra VM storage, without having to resize the system images.

Answer (score 0):

After putting this on the shelf for some time I figured out the issue was not a ZFS / Multipass issue.  I had installed multipass through snap and it did not have access to /mnt or other root directories.  The returned error was misleading me as it pointed to the folder not existing instead of a permissions error.

The solution for me was to move the mount point to a folder in the /home/ directory which snaps have access to.  Now I create a new user for each vm and mount the zfs filesystem into a folder in that users home folder.